How to install GLIBC_2.34 on Ubuntu 20.04
To run a program that is designed for internal use, it requires GLIBC_2.34. Ubuntu 20.04 is installed on the computer, where GLIBC_2.31 is available. How do I install GLIBC_2.34 on Ubuntu 20.04 or how do I use it for the program?

It's generally not recommended to mess with the default GLIBC version, but instead to compile the application using the GLIBC version on your server.

... or upgrade your system to 22.04 which provides GLIBC_2.35
